# How to set different logging levels for console-writing and file-writing in java

Tags: spring-boot, logging, log4j, logback

I'm working on a spring boot application. I need WARN and above level logs to be written in file whereas INFO and above to be displayed in the console. How can I configure this in the application.properties file?

If logback.xml is necessary for this(or similar file for log4j), can you help me configure this using either of them??

Comment: you just have to define your two appenders and then setup the log level for each of them as you want them to be. You will find everything you need to create you logback.xml or log4j config file in the documentation .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample logback.xml for writing each level log to a unique file and all above INFO to console.

I guess things are self explanatory. If you don't think so, you my friend should spend some time with the official documentation.

Hope it helps. Cheers.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <property name="DEV_HOME" value="logs" />

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>



    <appender name="FILE-ERROR"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${DEV_HOME}/error.log</file>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>ERROR</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>

    </appender>



    <appender name="FILE-INFO"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${DEV_HOME}/info.log</file>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/info.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>

    </appender>



    <appender name="FILE-FATAL"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${DEV_HOME}/fatal.log</file>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>FATAL</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/fatal.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>

    </appender>


    <appender name="FILE-WARN"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${DEV_HOME}/warn.log</file>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>WARN</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/warn.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>

    </appender>


    <!-- Send logs to both console and file audit -->

    <logger name="com.vaidiksanatansewa.guruji" level="fatal"
            additivity="false">

        <appender-ref ref="FILE-FATAL" />
    </logger>


    <logger name="com.vaidiksanatansewa.guruji" level="error"
            additivity="false">

        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ERROR" />
    </logger>


    <logger name="com.vaidiksanatansewa.guruji" level="warn"
            additivity="false">

        <appender-ref ref="FILE-WARN" />
    </logger>


    <logger name="com.vaidiksanatansewa.guruji" level="info"
            additivity="false">

        <appender-ref ref="FILE-INFO" />
    </logger>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>




</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was in a hurry so I was wanting some direct help instead of going through all those documentations. This works exactly as I wanted it to. But I had been studying the documentations after one of the comments and I guess these things make pretty much sense to me now. Cheers